# How to clone memberships, display as new tab?

Tags: civimember

We need to track student levels (rank) in our martial arts organization.

Each rank is essentially a paid membership (so contributions should be recorded) that doesn't expire, but we need to display the levels in their own tab on the contact summary page, not under memberships.

Answer (score 1):

Pair up the membership with custom data.  Create a a field set, and mark it to display as a tab (instead of inline).  Associate the fields with the type of membership, and then you'll collect paid contributions and generate fields in a separate tab.